# removing duplicate columns from a huge dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates, spark-streaming

So let's say i have huge dataframes and I am joining them using 'left' join in pyspark. Now after joining them I am seeing that some column names are being duplicated due the same column being present in multiple dataframes. What should be the best and the most efficient technique to identify these duplicated columns and remove them ? I know I can check the dataframe myself or perhaps only select the columns that I need but still what if the dataframe was too big to see every column and perhaps i want to print every column present in every dataframe but with the criteria that no column should be duplicated. Please help.

So I got my desired result using the select method where I got the correct output but what if i needed all the columns and none of them should be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the join, rename the columns like `df1.col_i`  and `df2.col_j` then select only required columns. Rename the selected columns after joining the dataframes if required. Example code given below.

```
data1 = [
    ["01001", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01001", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],

      ]

df1Columns = ["county", "bin_number",   "age_group1",   "age_group2",   "t_group1_1",   "t_group2_1",   "t_group1_2",   "t_group2_2"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

columns_list = df1.columns
print("columns list of dataframes")
print(columns_list)
print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


columns_list_new = ["tableA." + name for name in columns_list ]
df1_mod = df1.toDF(*columns_list_new)

print("columns list of modified dataframes")
print(df1_mod.columns)
print("Printing modified dataframe")
df1_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
columns list of dataframes
['county', 'bin_number', 'age_group1', 'age_group2', 't_group1_1', 't_group2_1', 't_group1_2', 't_group2_2']
Given dataframe
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|county|bin_number|age_group1|age_group2|t_group1_1|t_group2_1|t_group1_2|t_group2_2|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|01001 |1         |5         |10        |200       |100       |300       |400       |
|01001 |2         |1         |2         |100       |200       |300       |400       |
|01003 |1         |5         |10        |200       |100       |300       |400       |
|01003 |2         |1         |2         |100       |200       |300       |400       |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

columns list of modified dataframes
['tableA.county', 'tableA.bin_number', 'tableA.age_group1', 'tableA.age_group2', 'tableA.t_group1_1', 'tableA.t_group2_1', 'tableA.t_group1_2', 'tableA.t_group2_2']
Printing modified dataframe
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|tableA.county|tableA.bin_number|tableA.age_group1|tableA.age_group2|tableA.t_group1_1|tableA.t_group2_1|tableA.t_group1_2|tableA.t_group2_2|
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|01001        |1                |5                |10               |200              |100              |300              |400              |
|01001        |2                |1                |2                |100              |200              |300              |400              |
|01003        |1                |5                |10               |200              |100              |300              |400              |
|01003        |2                |1                |2                |100              |200              |300              |400              |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```